# In R plumber API, list gets larger (recursively) when serialized/deserialized across multiple calls

Tags: r, json, serialization, plumber

I have set up a simple general-purpose [Plumber](https://www.rplumber.io/) API that runs HTTP-posted R syntax (generated from a controlled HTML/JS client), obviously delivering back results as JSON. It is stateless: no info is ever saved in the Plumber R server environment. Works fine.

Now, I have added the possibility of some shared state among subsequent requests.
R syntax generated on the client can now interact with a "persistent" `starenv` list.

This list is newly created on the server on first invocation (in serialized version: see default value for `serStarEnv` parameter below), deserialized, possibly altered by posted syntax, then serialized and sent back to the client. The client saves it in a JS variable and reposts it on subsequent requests, thus achieving persistence. Obviously, on the Plumber API side, this always requires de-serialization on the input side, and serialization on the output side.

Now, this works too: later calls can access items from this "persistent" list.

However, there is some mysterious behaviour after an object is first added to the list (see example call below):

1. if later calls do *not* change the list, this is correctly preserved and passed back and forth across calls, *without any size change*;
2. when a later call changes the list (even with a size-invariant operation, e.g. by reposting the same syntax, so that it replaces an existing object with the same thing), the serialized object *multiplies in size* (roughly by a factor of 4).

By placing some inspection code in the API, I even found out that while *deserialized versions keep the correct size*, only their *serialized counterparts grow much larger* (see screenshot below): `oldSize` and `newSize` (deserialized) do not grow, while `oldSerSize` and `newSerSize` (serialized versions) show a large growth. Of course, this quickly makes the whole application unusable.

Now, what am I getting wrong here?

api.R:

```
#* @get /cmdsink
#* @post /cmdsink
function(command, serStarEnv=rawToChar(serialize(list(),NULL,ascii=TRUE))) {
  
  library(evaluate)
  
  # deserialize original environment (either from init, or posted with request)
  starenv <- unserialize(charToRaw(serStarEnv));

  # for testing: make serialized copy of original environment
  serOldStarEnv <- rawToChar(serialize(starenv,NULL,ascii=TRUE));
  
  # save size of original environment
  oldSize <- object.size(starenv);
  
  # run posted syntax
  result <- evaluate(command);
  
  # save size of environment, as altered by posted syntax
  newSize <- object.size(starenv);

  # make serialized copy of altered environment
  serStarEnv <- rawToChar(serialize(starenv,NULL,ascii=TRUE));
  
  # save sizes of serialized versions
  oldSerSize <- object.size(serOldStarEnv);
  newSerSize <- object.size(serStarEnv);
  
  # I interrupt execution here to inspect sizes (see attached screenshot)

  toJSON(
    list(result,serStarEnv)
  , force = TRUE);
}
```

Example request:

```
{
  "command": "filename <- \"http://cise.luiss.it/files/opcp/201204.dta\";\nstardata <- haven::read_dta(filename);\n\n\nres <- lm(ptv_pdl ~ ptv_pd + ptv_idv + ptv_ln + ptv_sel + ptv_m5s + ptv_udc + ptv_sc + ptv_ast, data=stardata);\nstarenv$est1 <- res \n",
  "serStarEnv": "A\n3\n262149\n197888\n6\nCP1252\n19\n0\n"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Using `jsonlite::serializeJSON()` everything works correctly (also does not need rawToChar/charToRow anymore).